# Android Studio Google map api and API key for release

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

For android studio google map api, when you generate a signed APK in android studio does the API key get updated in the   android code for release?

Answer (score 1):

> when you generate a signed APK in android studio does the API key get updated in the android code for release?

Android Studio does not issue API Keys for Google Maps API. You change your API Keys in the Google APIs Console. So, you will be using the same API Key.

Now, there are a few things you need to take into consideration. If you add package restrictions to your API key, you normally have to provide a SHA-1 signature which is unique to your app. This signature does change between **Build Variants** (debug, release, etc.). So, when you generate signed APK for the Release Build Variant, the app's SHA-1 signature will be different. And you will need to reflect that on the API Key settings (if you have restrictions configured) by:

1- Adding the new SHA-1 signature and package name in the list of restrictions. See image below

[image]

2- Or, by creating a new API Key dedicated to the release variant only and adding the necessary package restrictions there.

#### Retrieving the SHA-1 signature

There are plenty of information out there about how you can find the SHA-1 signature of your package(s). Mostly using the `keytool` utility which is provided by the JDK (I think).

Yet, the easiest way to retrieve the SHA-1 fingerprint of your application package is by running the signing report gradle task in Android Studio. To do that:

1- Expand the "Gradle" tool window

2- And navigate to your app module's signing report task

[image]

3- Double-click the `signingReport` to run it

4- It will produce the `MD5`, `SHA-1` and a `SHA-256` fingerprint in the "Run" window

[image]

Comment: So will the API key be different in final release version upon generating APK release in Android Studio?

Comment: No, never. Unless you're using different API Keys for different build variants or product flavours

Comment: well then I don't understand my google map shows in emulator but not live downloaded and installed on a actually device??

Comment: I checked my release XML. seems at the point of APK generated the map api key is not populated in the release XML for me

Comment: I now have a SHA1 for debug variant and another SHA1 for release variant. And I have the API key in the XML. Still does not work in release version. Any idea?